# cx_freeze not seeing sqlalchemy under windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, cx-freeze

I'm using Python 3.2 32bit with sqlalchemy installed. I have written quite simple script in Python using sqlalchemy. I'm importing it like that:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
```

The script is working correctly. I want to make .exe with `cx_freeze`. So i wrote following `setup.py` file:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "dev_db",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "Device Database System",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("./dev_db/db_main/db_init.py", base=base)])
```

(The application is part of bigger package containing other applications)

After launching `setup.py build` everything goes fine except:

```
? sqlalchemy imported from db_init__main__, dev_db.common.alchemy_base, dev_db.common.devinfo_io, dev_db.common.event_io
? sqlalchemy.engine.reflection imported from db_init__main__
? sqlalchemy.ext.declarative imported from dev_db.common.alchemy_base, dev_db.common.event_io
? sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid imported from dev_db.common.devinfo_io, dev_db.common.event_io
? sqlalchemy.orm imported from db_init__main__, dev_db.common.alchemy_base, dev_db.common.devinfo_io
```

The .exe is created but it won't work-it seems that cx_freeze cannot see the sqlalchemy which is obviously installed!

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Where is SQLalchemy installed? cx_Freeze sometimes has problems with .egg directories, but I can't reproduce them.

Comment: In python_dir\Lib\site-packages\SQLAlchemy-0.8.4-py3.2.egg. So it is indeed an egg. Do you think it's a problem for cx_Freeze? Can I somehow extract it?

Comment: Try copying the `sqlalchemy` folder out of the .egg folder, up one level into the `site-packages` directory, and then freezing again.

Comment: You mean to open .egg file with e.x. zip and extract `sqlalchemy` into `site-packages` right?

Comment: I've done it and it helped. Please write an answer so I can accept it :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cx_Freeze appears to have some problems with packages installed as eggs (possibly where the egg is a zip file). Open the folder or zip file ending in `.egg`, and copy the package - the `sqlalchemy` folder in this case - up one level into the `site-packages` directory. Then re-freeze it, and cx_Freeze should find the package.